# Apache Shiro is not Authenticated in Tomcat afetr restart Oracle sql db

Tags: tomcat, shiro

```
    ##Shiro config file  
##IronOne Technologies (Pvt) Ltd

[main]
              
##creating the realm
  jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
  jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true

##  jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?
##  jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT rolename FROM userroles WHERE username = ?
  
##   jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT permission FROM rolepermissions WHERE roleid=(SELECT roleid from roles where rolename= ? )

  jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM users WHERE UPPER(LOGIN_ID) = UPPER(?)
  jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT ROLE_ID FROM users WHERE UPPER(LOGIN_ID) = UPPER(?)
  ##jdbcRealm.connectionTmeout = 60
##connection pooling and database access through apache commons dbcp
##  ds = src.com.ironone.backoffice.controller.shiro.ShiroBasicDataSource
    ds = org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
  ds.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  ds.username=BACKOFFICE
  ds.password =backoffice
  ds.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.25.27:1521:orcl

  securityManager.rememberMeManager.cipherKey = kPH+bIxk5D2deZiIxcaaaA==
              
##adding the data source to the realm earlier configured
  jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
               
##password encryption is done by sha256 encryption algorithm provided by shiro api
  Md5Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Md5CredentialsMatcher
  jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $Md5Matcher
               
##configuring security manager to use the realm configured earlier
  securityManager.realms=$jdbcRealm
               
##Caching mechanism is dome by a third party chaching api called ehcache
##adding the chaching support to the security manager
 ## cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
 ## securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager 
  
##  rememberMeManager = src.com.ironone.backoffice.controller.shiro.MyRememberMeManager
##  securityManager.rememberMeManager = $rememberMeManager
  
## sessionManager = src.com.ironone.backoffice.controller.shiro.CustomSecurityManager
 logout = src.com.ironone.backoffice.controller.shiro.MyLogoutFilter
[filters]

##   authcBasic.loginUrl =/home_
##   authcBasic.successUrl = /home
##   logout.redirectUrl =/logoutc
                
##url section is used to set permissions to specific urls
[urls]
/logout = logout
/login = anon
/= anon
 /login.jsp = anon  
/home=anon
/jquery.js = anon
/js/shiro_logout.js = anon
/atrad_style.css = anon
/FooterFile.css = anon
/Img/loginImage/* = anon
/Img/top_bck.gif = anon
/Img/top_curve_front.gif = anon
/Img/atrad_backOffice_logo.png = anon
/Img/top_curve_end.gif = anon
/Img/nav_panel_bck.jpg = anon
/Img/but_bck.jpg = anon
/LoginController=anon
/login_=anon

                           
               /js = anon
               /** = authc
 ##              /** = authcBasic
```

Comment: What have you tried already? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Finally i got th answer

Comment: need to add {ds.validationQuery = select 1 from dual}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add `ds.validationQuery = select 1 from dual` part to shiro.ini file so bug was fixed

```
      ds.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
      ds.username=<schima name>
      ds.password=<password-here>
      ds.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl    
      ds.validationQuery = select 1 from dual
```